# Search string in a list

Tags: python, performance, strings, python-2.x, search

```
data = ['HTTP/1.1 200 OK', 'CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=1810', 'DATE: Wed, 14 May 2014 12:15:19 GMT', 'EXT:', 'LOCATION: http://192.168.94.57:9000/DeviceDescription.xml', 'SERVER: Windows NT/5.0, UPnP/1.0, pvConnect UPnP SDK/1.0', 'ST: uuid:7076436f-6e65-1063-8074-78542e239ff5', 'USN: uuid:7076436f-6e65-1063-8074-78542e239ff5', 'Content-Length: 0', '', '']
```

From the above list, I have to extract the `.xml` link.

My code:

```
for element in data:
    if 'LOCATION' in element:
        xmllink = element.split(': ').[1]
```

It's taking too much time.  How can I make this faster?

Actually I am doing SSDP discovery for finding devices in a network.  After sending the M-SEARCH command, devices send a datagram packet which I have taken in a `data` variable.  From this I have to extract the file link of that device for processing it.

When I use indexing to extract, it was done quickly.

Comment: I cannot understand how a split and a small array like that can take too much time. Have you use some sort of profiling to make sure that this part is the problem?

Comment: @Marc-Andre actually i am doing ssdp dicovery for devices in network, after sending M-SEARCH command devices respond with a datagram packet which i have taken in "data" and its taking so much time to process this, earlier i have used direct indexing to find "LOCATION" and it was done quickly

Comment: those information are important for a review! You should edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

You want to test for `element.startswith('LOCATION: ')`.  You are doing `'LOCATION' in element`, which is not only slower since it has to check at every position of every `element`, it might also lead to false matches.

Also, `element` and `data` are poor names.  I suggest `header` and `headers`, respectively.

My suggestion:

```
LOC = 'LOCATION: '
xmllinks = [header[len(LOC):] for header in headers if header.startswith(LOC)]
if xmllinks:
    xmllink = xmllinks[0]
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume there will be a single space after 'LOCATION:' based on his original implementation? Searching for simply 'LOCATION:' then using `strip()` to remove any additional white space would probably be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

With such a small input it should be lightning fast. Anyway, shouldn't you break after finding the element? I'd write:

```
xmllink = next(s.split(":", 1)[1].strip() for s in data if s.startswith("LOCATION:")
```

Comment: how does this code ensures speedup ?

Comment: because it breaks after finding the match. Not sure how the OP is having speed problems here, though

Comment: @tokland Read the comments under the question, he's giving a bit more information about the speed problem.

Comment: While I agree with the `break` suggestion, I think using regex is totally overkill.

Comment: some refactors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is causing problem. This piece of code should not take up a lot of time. But here are some of the suggestions to speed up your code:

1. Instead of list, create a set. The lookup time in set is constant.
2. But the main problem with set is uses up more memory in comparison to list. So another option is to keep a sorted list (if possible) and use the bisect module to search the list.

Now some style suggestions:

```
for element in data:
  if 'LOCATION' in element:
    xmllink = element.split(': ').[1]
```

rewrite it as

```
for element in data:
   if 'LOCATION' in element and ':' in element:
     xmllink = element.split(':')[1].strip()
```

This ensures that if a string like 'LOCATION something' is in list then it will not raise any errors.

The .strip() is a better way to remove trailing whitespaces

Comment: Using a set only works if you want to check the whole element, `set.contains("LOCATION: http://www.example.com/test.xml")` would be fast, but what is needed here is something like `set.startsWith("LOCATION: ")`, which doesn't exist.